# Rolling updates for websites hosted on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my application to Elastic Beanstalk, and configured it with the Rolling Updates feature. This sounds pretty cool because it keeps a certain number of servers in the farm at all times while others are swapped out for upgrades - so it seems an outage-less upgrade is achievable.

But by my reasoning this just isn't going to work - at some point during a rolling update there will be some servers with v1 on and some servers with v2 on. If the JS or CSS is different between v1 and v2 then there could be a v1 page loaded that sends a request to the load balancer and gets the v2 JS/CSS and vice versa.

I can't think of an easy way to avoid this, and so I'm struggling to see the point of Rolling Upgrades at all.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to achieve an outage-less upgrade for a website? I was thinking that I could also set up a complete parallel Elastic Beanstalk environment with v2 on it, and then switch them over in one go - but that seems so much more time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you described, to use rolling deployments and have continuous deployments on the same environment, you need to guarantee that version N is compatible with version N+1. "Compatible" meaning they can run simultaneously, what can be challenging in cases such as different files and database schema changes.

A popular workaround to that is [Blue-Green Deployments](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html), where you deploy to a different environment and then redirect users. The [Swap URL feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) helps to implement that using AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Progressive rollouts and blue-green are not mutually exclusive. You can use progressive rollouts for small changes and blue-green for bigger ones. For more patterns and techniques on continuos delivery, i'd recommend you check [Jez Humble's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912).

Comment: Good advice. I think I could do a blue/green deployment by setting up an additional load-balancer ($30/month) - but with a blue website and a green website on each server. Then the blue load-balancer could forward the port 80/443 traffic to the blue server ports, and the green load-balancer could forward the  port 80/443 traffic to the green server ports. So a process for a blue deployment might be (1) Update AMI with current green build and latest blue build. (2) Apply rolling upgrade of new AMI, but still using green load-balancer. (3) Switch the active load-balancer over to blue in Route53.